# When I Try to migrate module from odoo15 to odoo16

Tags: python, odoo-15, odoo-16

When I try to update module from odoo15 to odoo16 after change version to 16 and when I try to update get's this error below any solution can help me
The above server error caused the following client error:

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')
at ClientErrorDialog.onClickClipboard (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:6726:37) (/web/static/src/core/errors/error_dialogs.js:36)
at Object.mainEventHandler (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:21896:25) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:5836)
at HTMLButtonElement.listener (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:16417:20) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:357)*